# How to enforce calling order of destructors

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am trying to get the following setup right:

A given application (with multiple source files, compilation units) has global variables of type `class A` defined in many compilation units.
These should be "managed" by a new to introduce `class B` (where only 1 instance should exist) in the sense that upon creation they "register" themselves at instance of class B and at destruction "sign off".

Setting the thing up for the constructors to work is fairly straight-forward. One can use:

`types.h`:

```
class B {
  static B& Instance() {
    static B singleton;
    return singleton;
  }
  void registerA( const A& a ) { 
  // whatever
  }
};


class A {
  A() { B::Instance().registerA( this ); }
};
```

How to get the destructors right? If using:

```
class A {
  A() { B::Instance().registerA( this ); }
  ~A() { B::Instance().signoffA( this ); }
};
```

then the destructor of `B` might be called before the destructor of `A`.
Then the instance of class `A` signs off at a just newly created instance of `B`.

The test case would be a multi source file setup with definitions of instances of `class A` in a namespace:

`file1.cc`

```
#include "types.h"
namespace C {
   A a;
}
```

`file2.cc`

```
#include "types.h"
namespace C {
   A b;
}
```

I guess on can do such thing easily with Boost smart pointers. However, if possible I would like to avoid using additional libraries to keep dependence as low as possible.

One thing that might help: All global variables are in a named namespace.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and scoping.

Comment: Also, please consider creating a short coherent test-case to illustrate where your `A` instance is created in relation to everything else.  It's a little confusing currently.

Comment: Note that `register` is keyword in C++ and C, and thus your code does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're fine. Here's 3.6.3 on "Termination":

> If the completion of the constructor or dynamic initialization of an object with static storage duration is sequenced before that of another, the completion of the destructor of the second is sequenced before the initiation of the destructor of the first.

Suppose you have the following setup:

```
struct A;

struct B
{
    static B & get() { static B impl; return impl; }
    void registrate(A *);

private:
    B() { /* complex stuff */ }
    // ...
};

struct A { A() { B::get().registrate(this); } };

A a1;
```

Now whatever happens, the first constructor of a static `A`-type object will call `B::get()`, which sequences the construction of the static `impl` object before the completion of the first `A`-constructor. By the above clause, this guarantees that the destructor of the `B impl`-object is sequenced *after* all the `A`-destructors.

Comment: Doesn't the quoted statement refer to the case where both objects are of static storage duration? In my case just one of it is `static`.

Comment: I don't get it: .."the first constructor of a static A-type". `A` is not static.

Comment: @Frank: "static" doesn't mean what you think. Everything in the example has static storage duration. The keyword `static` is just one of many, many ways to make an object with static storage duration.

Comment: Oh ok. The default storage duration for global variable have `static` duration. And that's why the statement applies here.

Comment: @Frank: Not "default". Simply "is". The storage duration of a global variable *is* 'static'.

Comment: Awesome! Makes perfect sense. The setup is okay! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The `B` instance is static, so it will outlive any `A` instance created after the `B` singleton has been created.

Comment: This is certainly true if all objects are in the same compilation unit. This is not the case here. I am not sure if `static` object destruction is deferred also across compilation units

Comment: @Frank I can not see how it wouldn't apply across compilation units.

Comment: Yes, the setup is okay. But the reason is the order of calling constructors and the fact that its static. If you meant both circumstances at the same time, you are right